# clip-path polygon for mozilla is not working

Tags: css, svg, mozilla

Is it possible in Mozilla to achieved the style given? I used clip path in css but when i tried to test it on mozila the clip-path is not working

[image]

Comment: not yet supported (implementation is in progress though), you can achieve the same with an SVG clipPath though.

Comment: i tried to use SVG but i can't achieved the exact style

Comment: <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>  this is the code that i found for SVG but i can't resize it to full with and full height :(

Comment: Add that to the question, markup in comments is unreadable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox has partial support only supporting the `clip-path: url()` syntax.
So to make this work in FF you can use an inline svg and define a clipPath to be used as the url. Make sure to set the `clipPathUnits` attribute on the clipPath to `objectBoundingBox` then the content of the clipPath is using the bounding box of the element.

Here is an example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.wrapper > li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.clip {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 75% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 75% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clipping");
  clip-path: url("#clipping");
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/512x288/3498db/f1f1f1" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="clip" src="http://placehold.it/512x288/e67e22/f1f1f1" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>

<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0.25 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0.75 1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```